# How to write a perfect Exception Mapper?

Tags: java, exception

I read about custom exception and as:

> Thorben suggest here:
>   https://stackify.com/java-custom-exceptions/#wpautbox_about
>
> Baeldung suggested here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-new-custom-exception

A custom exception should be more beneficial than the original exception, otherwise it would loose its purpose.Right?
To do that we should always pass the throwable cause to our custom exception.
I have my application specific `ErrorCode` enums which have a custom error code and a custom message.

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ErrorType {
    DATABASE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE(9001, "Cant persist to Database"),
    //and more...
    private final int errorCode;
    private final String errorMessage;
}
```

> While writing a exception mapper what should I send as response?
>
> 1)Custom ErrorCode Enum (Only errorcode and error msg)
>
> OR
>
> 2)Custom ErrorCode Enum + Throwable cause (Both)

If we not send throwable, then what would be its purpose?

Comment: why do you need an exception mapper ? Response from web service request ?

Comment: Yup, it has APIs and controllers.

Comment: @Getter? @AllArgsConstructor?  Don’t use Lombok!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen `Don't use Lombok!` it is opinion-based ...Am I wrong? ;-)

Comment: @CodeScale When I looked at it, Lombok achieves some very nice things in a very nasty way.  Java 14 has records for this purpose, which in my opinion is reason enough on its own to upgrade.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen agree for Record. Regarding Lombok did you have some nasty example :-) ? Maybe it is better to discuss that in another channel type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While writing a exception mapper what should I send as response?

If by "response", you mean the response returned by a Controller, then I think you should *send the error code and error message*. Why would a client be interested in your throwable object. Just give the client an understandable reason for the error. You should just log the exception in your application for debugging purpose.

Comment: Whats the use of adding throwable then? Also sending instead of sending a custom msg, would it be better  to send the original exception msg?

Comment: The throwable object is of no use for a client. Its for the developer/support person to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: It could still interesting for dev/debugging purpose... instead of look inside your logs you can push in "dev" environment the stacktrace in response. Could allow faster debugging.